# How to get the output in a for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have created bigrams using a for loop in the code. But I am not able to extract it out of the loop.

```
for(w in j)
{
 BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x,Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
 k <- BigramTokenizer(w)
 print(k)   #returns all words in the loop
}

k  #only return the words in the last sentence
```

How can I get the entire output out of the for loop on calling variable 'k'?

Comment: There are several ways. You can use the `<<-` (which is not preferable) or the `assign` function.

Comment: The bigram function does not vary with `w`, so you should take its definition out of the loop. Or better, don't bother defining it at all: `lapply(j, NGramTokenizer, Weka_control(min=2,max=2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get a list of the `k` variables generated within the loop. You can do so with the `lapply` function:

```
results <- lapply(j, function(w) {
  BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x,Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
  k <- BigramTokenizer(w)
  return(k)
})
```

Now you can access the `k` values for the first element of `j` with `results[[1]]`, the results for the second element of `j` with `results[[2]]`, and so on.